# How to convert stringified array into array in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

It so happens I have a stringified array in a field in BigQuery

```
'["a","b","c"]'
```

and I want to convert it to an array that BigQuery understands.
I want to be able to do this in standard SQL:

```
with k as (select '["a","b","c"]' as x)
select unnested_x from k, unnest(x) unnested_x
```

I have tried `JSON_EXTRACT('["a","b","c"]','$')` and everything else I could find online.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH k AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '["a","b","c"]' AS x UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '["x","y"]' 
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  ARRAY(SELECT * FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(SUBSTR(x, 2 , LENGTH(x) - 2)))) AS x
FROM k
```

It transforms your string column into array column

Comment: this works for a simple array (which the OP asked about), but doesn't handle more complex json unnesting.

Comment: @RyanTuck - obviously provided answer is for specific question! if you need more generic solution - please post your question with respective details - and I (or someone else here on SO) will be happy to help you :o)

Comment: definitely! i did find a more generic solution using a UDF and added my own answer here :) - do you know if this is possible to accomplish without resorting to UDFs?

Comment: @RyanTuck - i just don't see any needs in more generic/expensive solution for case in given question. If you feel you have use-case which does require - post your question so we will answer it :o)

Comment: I agree for the given question a more generic solution is unnecessary. I've asked the more generic question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57117805/unnest-stringified-array-of-json-objects-in-bigquery

Answer (score 25):

Recently (2020) the `JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY` function was added to the bigquery standard sql.

It makes it easy to get the expected behavior with no UDF or tricks

```sql
with k as (select JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY('["a","b","c"]', '$') as x)
select unnested_x from k, unnest(x) unnested_x
```

Will result in:

```
╔══════════════╗
║ "unnested_x" ║
╠══════════════╣
║     "a"      ║
║     "b"      ║
║     "c"      ║
╚══════════════╝
```

[JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array)

Answer (score 6):

This solution updates @northtree's answer, and more elegantly handles returning the members of the array as stringified JSON objects as opposed to returning `[object Object]` strings:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(input STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """  
return JSON.parse(input).map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
""";

with

raw as (
  select
    1 as id,
    '[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7}, 456]' as body
)

select
  id,
  entry,
  json_extract(entry, '$'),
  json_extract(entry, '$.a'),
  json_extract(entry, '$.b')
from
  raw,
  unnest(json_extract_array(body)) as entry
```

Answer (score 4):

I want to offer an alternative. As the array is a string, simply extract the value using regexp_extract_all:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(your_string, r'[0-9a-zA-Z][^"]+') as arr
```

You may find the regex too restrictive to start with an alphanumeric; you can just tweak it to your liking.

Answer (score 2):

It would be much easier via `JS` [UDF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions).

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(input STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """  
return JSON.parse(input);
""";
WITH
  k AS (
  SELECT
    '["a","b","c"]' AS x)
SELECT
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(x) AS x
FROM
  k
```