# best way to store and compare vectors of integers in Google BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

We have a use case for datasets with 5-6 numerical/float/string fields, plus another field with a vector of integers, that can range from 0 to hundreds or thousands of integers. Most of the time the value of the integers will be between 1 and 1000, with a small tail that can go bigger than that, to 10E6 or 10E7, but we are willing to discard those if necessary.

What is the best way to store the vectors of integers in BigQuery, together with the other 5-6 fields, so that the vectors can be efficiently compared in a pairwise or multiway manner? E.g. running a Mann Whitney test on pairs of vectors (records), or testing if a set of 1000 vectors is significantly different than a set of another 1000 vectors? We would run these tests for a feature set (number of records) of around 20,000-500,000 features.

Any ideas?

Currently I would opt to store them as the value below:

```
{132,234,641,123,4123,132,34,43,213,123,34,132}
```

EDIT:

After some investigating, it seems like the best way to store these is as double-quoted strings, e.g.:

```
"132,234,641,123,4123,132,34,43,213,123,34,132"
```

Then apply some preprocessing and an UNNEST() function to convert the stringified array into an array at query time:

[How to convert stringified array into array in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199823/how-to-convert-stringified-array-into-array-in-bigquery)

I am currently struggling to use `bq load` to populate the table from a .csv file:

$ num=11 && bq load --source_format=CSV insert_size_by_region.insert_size_by_region${num} /tmp/${num}.csv
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r43db3fbe8e450141_0000016717136592_1 ... (0s) Current status: DONE
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'test-project1:bqjob_r43db3fbe8e450141_0000016717136592_1': Error while reading data, error message: CSV table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1. Please look into the error stream for
more details.
Failure details:
- Error while reading data, error message: Could not parse 'count' as
int for field count (position 2) starting at location 0

Comment: Did you try storing them in arrays? If they are vectors that seems like the natural choice?

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann would that simply entail changing to `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` instead of `{1,2,3,4,5,6}`? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Depends, how you load the data. Here's a good overview: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays In principle, you can treat arrays as tables and apply SQL on them, which is pretty cool.

Comment: @MartinWeitzmann will read, thanks again.

Comment: Would be nice if you could share your solution :)