# Unnest stringified array of json objects in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table that contains a `string` column containing a stringified list of JSON objects like so:

```
'[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8}]'
```

I would like to unnest this array, and then use `json_extract()` or `json_extract_scalar()` to get the values out of these objects.

It's unclear from [BigQuery's JSON Function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions) that I'm able to do so using baked-in functionality.

**Is a UDF required to accomplish this, or does this functionality exist in BigQuery?**

The below UDF accomplishes what I'm looking for:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(input STRING)
  RETURNS ARRAY<STRING>
  LANGUAGE js AS """  
return JSON.parse(input).map(x => JSON.stringify(x));
""";

with

raw as (
  select
    1 as id,
    '[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8}]' as body
)

select
  id,
  json_extract(entry, '$.a') as a,
  json_extract(entry, '$.b') as b
from
  raw,
  unnest(json_extract_array(body)) as entry
```

Comment: looks like you have solution - what is the question here? do you want solution that does not involve UDF? or something else? please clarify - as whatever yo highlighted/bolded is still not clear to me

Comment: please vote for https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63716683

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought my question was pretty clear. To rephrase: "Is a UDF required to accomplish this, or does BigQuery Standard SQL support unnesting stringified JSON arrays without the need for a UDF?"

Comment: It's unclear to me why this question was downvoted without a suggestion as to what could make it better. To anyone stumbling on this, it is still a legitimate open question, though Felipe Hoffa's comment does contain a link tracking this missing feature if anyone would like to add a vote to it.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
with

raw as (
    select
        1 as id,
        '[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8}]' as body
)

select
    r.id,
    r.body,
    regexp_extract_all(r.body, r'({.*?})'),
    json_extract(entry, '$.a') as a,
    json_extract(entry, '$.b') as b
from
    raw as r
    cross join  unnest(
                    regexp_extract_all(r.body, r'({.*?})')
                ) as entry
```

or a slightly more general solution

```
with

raw as (
    select
        1 as id,
        '[{"a": 5, "b": {"x": 1, "y": 2}}, {"b": {"c": 5, "d": 8}, "a": 7}]' as body
)

select
    r.id,
    r.body,
    split(trim(r.body, '[]{}'), '}, {'),
    json_extract(concat('{', entry, '}'), '$.a') as a,
    json_extract(concat('{', entry, '}'), '$.b') as b
from
    raw as r
    cross join  unnest(
                    split(trim(r.body, '[]{}'), '}, {')
                ) as entry
```

Comment: This is nifty, and the example code works as expected to solve the problem without recourse to a UDF. I'll kick the tires with this - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Google has added the function [JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_array) to their Standard SQL so this can now be accomplished without a UDF.  In fact, since the UDF name in the OP is the same name (JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY) you can run that query below the UDF as is and it will work.

If performance matters, rather than completely denormalizing the table, you can also take advantage of [BigQuery's nesting capabilities](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) by extracting the body data into a repeated record.

```
with 
    raw as (
        select
            1 as id,
            '[{"a": 5, "b": 6}, {"a": 7, "b": 8}]' as body
    )

select
    r.id,
    array(
        select
            struct (
                json_value(items, '$.a') as a,
                json_value(items, '$.b') as b
            ) as b 
        from unnest(json_extract_array(body, '$')) as items
    ) as body_record_repeated
from raw r
```

which will return

[BigQuery repeated record result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTv0q.png)