# Extract keys and values from json string in bigquery where there is no specified key in the json document

Tags: json, google-bigquery, json-extract

I have a table in bigquery where I have object and for each object I have some stringified json. In json, an example row look like below:

```
{
    "ObjectID": "1984931229",
    "indexed_abstract": "{\"IndexLength\":123,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"Twenty-seven\":[0],\"metastatic\":[1,45],\"breast\":[2],\"adenocarcinoma\":[3],\"patients,\":[4]}}" 
}
```

where inside the `indexed_abstract` we have an `InvertedIndex` which contains some keywords and how many times these keywords appeared in the `ObjectID`.

Now I want to access the stringified json by parsing the json using bigquery and for each `ObjectID` I want to create a nested field where I have the keyword, the corresponding array and the length of the corresponding array.

For example in this case the output would look like the following:

```
+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
|  ObjectID  |  keyword.key   | keyword.count | keyword.positions |
+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
| 1984931229 | Twenty-seven   |             1 | [0]               |
|            | metastatic     |             2 | [1,45]            |
|            | breast         |             1 | [2]               |
|            | adenocarcinoma |             1 | [3]               |
|            | patients       |             1 | [4]               |
+------------+----------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

I understand I could use JSON_EXTRACT function but I am not sure what would be my key inside the inverted index to access the keywords and the arrays corresponding to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ObjectID, 
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      key, 
      ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(value)) `count`, 
      value positions 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(indexed_abstract, '$.InvertedIndex'), r'"[^"]+":\[[\d,]*?]')) pair,
    UNNEST([STRUCT(REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"', '') AS key, SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
  ) keyword
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row ObjectID    keyword.key     keyword.count   keyword.positions    
1   1984931229  Twenty-seven    1               [0]  
                metastatic      2               [1,45]   
                breast          1               [2]  
                adenocarcinoma  1               [3]  
                patients        1               [4]
```

> Update on Op's comment - *I was wondering if I wanted to make the positions an array (a repeated field), how would I do that?*

Change needs to be done in just one line

```
  SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, r'\[|]', '')) positions
```

Comment: Wow, I that is complicated! Thanks though. I was wondering if I wanted to make the positions an array (a repeated field), how would I do that?

Comment: btw, i read your comment again and your extra ask is pretty simple  - so I will just update my answer - but i am on go right now  - so it will be later in a day :o)

Comment: actually it is quite simple and not much to type so I just added it to my answer now

Comment: I also tried your answer from here just now, that also work too! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199823/how-to-convert-stringified-array-into-array-in-bigquery . Thanks!