# BigQuery getting exhausted after a few json extraction

Tags: json, google-bigquery, json-extract

I have created a json extraction query from a string field in BigQuery following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121341/extract-keys-and-values-from-json-string-in-bigquery-where-there-is-no-specified). But interestingly this query is always working for a first few rows then it is returning empty result.

I checked whether the empty results are because they are malformed, but if I remove the rows of the first few correct output rows from the input table then again I am left with first few proper output rows and the rest of them are empty. It seems like BigQuery is getting exhausted after json extraction from string in first few rows.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ObjectID,
  ARRAY(
    SELECT AS STRUCT 
      key, 
      ARRAY_LENGTH(SPLIT(value)) `count`, 
      ARRAY(SELECT cast(x as int64) FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(SUBSTR(value, 2 , LENGTH(value) - 2))) x) AS positions 
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(JSON_EXTRACT(indexed_abstract, '$.InvertedIndex'), r'"[^"]+":\[[\d,]*?]')) pair,
    UNNEST([STRUCT(REPLACE(SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"', '') AS key, SPLIT(pair, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS value)])
  ) keyword
FROM `project.dataset.objects_100`
```

The input table `project.dataset.objects_100` is created from this newline delimited [objects_100.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jSClBz0Vp3sv1p7byLUcT3QqeYWAcFf3/view?usp=sharing) file.

When I run the above query on the input table in the output I get the correct result for the first 12 rows then for the following rows I get empty result which looks like below.

[image: empty result with non empty result for row 12]

I am also putting this strange output of the query as newline delimited json file in this [results_100.json](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o0c70FEiJqVd2fML0oEQ_XPDB9d6JYJi/view?usp=sharing) file.

Can someone help me figure out why the output for later rows are becoming empty?

Edit:

Here are a few rows of json where the query returned empty:

```
{"objectID":"2876639571","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":105,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"PROBLEM\":[0],\"TO\":[1],\"BE\":[2],\"SOLVED:\":[3],\"To\":[4],\"provide\":[5],\"an\":[6,68],\"optical\":[7,31],\"operation\":[8,32],\"processor\":[9],\"with\":[10,46,84],\"which\":[11],\"inputting/\":[12],\"outputting\":[13],\"from\":[14],\"plural\":[15,34],\"functional\":[16,20,35,98],\"elements\":[17,36,99],\"to\":[18],\"one\":[19],\"element\":[21],\"consisting\":[22],\"of\":[23,49,55,58],\"the\":[24,47,56,77,97],\"device\":[25,81],\"is\":[26,82],\"enabled.\":[27],\"SOLUTION:\":[28],\"Concerning\":[29],\"this\":[30,80],\"processor,\":[33],\"(thin\":[37],\"film\":[38],\"elements)\":[39],\"2,\":[40,100],\"4,\":[41,101],\"6\":[42,102],\"and\":[43,52,90,103],\"8\":[44],\"provided\":[45,83],\"monomolecule\":[48],\"organic\":[50],\"compound\":[51],\"nanoparticles\":[53],\"composed\":[54],\"aggregate/agglomerate\":[57],\"these\":[59],\"monomolecules\":[60],\"are\":[61],\"arranged\":[62],\"for\":[63,92],\"processing\":[64],\"information\":[65,74],\"by\":[66],\"operating\":[67],\"external\":[69],\"signal\":[70],\"upon\":[71],\"incidental\":[72],\"two-dimensional\":[73],\"light.\":[75],\"At\":[76],\"same\":[78],\"time,\":[79],\"light\":[85],\"sources\":[86],\"I,\":[87],\"II,\":[88],\"III\":[89],\"IV\":[91],\"transferring\":[93],\"image\":[94],\"signals\":[95],\"among\":[96],\"8.\":[104]}}"}
{"objectID":"2787463273","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":131,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"A\":[0],\"permanent-magnetic\":[1],\"stepping\":[2,16,38],\"motor\":[3,17,22,39],\"is\":[4,18,23,121],\"disclosed.\":[5],\"According\":[6],\"to\":[7,118],\"the\":[8,21,52,68,79,101,107,115,119],\"utility\":[9],\"model,\":[10],\"noise\":[11],\"of\":[12,31,67,82,100],\"a\":[13,36,41,49,74,83,97],\"salient-pole\":[14],\"PM-type\":[15,37],\"reduced\":[19],\"when\":[20],\"driven.\":[24],\"In\":[25],\"an\":[26,45,92,111],\"inner\":[27,53,64,102],\"magnet\":[28,54,65,94,103],\"yoke\":[29,95,104],\"(111)\":[30,56,105],\"each\":[32],\"stator\":[33,47],\"for\":[34,62,90],\"forming\":[35],\"with\":[40,78],\"structure\":[42],\"combined\":[43],\"by\":[44],\"A-phase\":[46],\"and\":[48,59,96,110,126],\"B-phase\":[50],\"stator,\":[51],\"yoke\\u0027s\":[55],\"closing\":[57],\"pin\":[58],\"hole\":[60],\"arranged\":[61],\"engaging\":[63],\"yokes\":[66],\"two\":[69,87],\"stators\":[70],\"are\":[71],\"positioned\":[72],\"at\":[73],\"line\":[75,81,117],\"symmetry\":[76,108],\"position\":[77,85,120],\"center\":[80,116],\"middle\":[84],\"between\":[86],\"bumps\":[88],\"(111e)\":[89],\"fitting\":[91],\"outer\":[93],\"central\":[98],\"point\":[99],\"as\":[106],\"axis;\":[109],\"angle\":[112],\"theta\":[113],\"from\":[114],\"less\":[122],\"than\":[123,128],\"90\":[124],\"degrees\":[125],\"greater\":[127],\"30\":[129],\"degrees.\":[130]}}"}
{"objectID":"2140096340","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":198,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"The\":[0],\"perceptual\":[1,25,141,183],\"subband\":[2,19],\"image\":[3,179],\"coder\":[4],\"(PIC)\":[5],\"introduced\":[6],\"by\":[7],\"Safranek\":[8],\"and\":[9,102,189],\"Johnston\":[10],\"(1989),\":[11],\"selects\":[12],\"a\":[13],\"noise\":[14,29],\"target\":[15,30],\"level\":[16,38],\"for\":[17,43,136,177],\"each\":[18,83,137],\"based\":[20,96],\"on\":[21,62,97,165],\"an\":[22,73,87],\"empirically\":[23],\"derived\":[24],\"masking\":[26,91],\"measure.\":[27,92],\"These\":[28],\"levels\":[31],\"are\":[32,155],\"used\":[33],\"to\":[34,57,86,111,130,150,161],\"set\":[35],\"the\":[36,40,63,66,78,90,98,105,112,114,128,132,143,157,166,169,182,194],\"quantization\":[37],\"in\":[39,156,193],\"DPCM\":[41],\"quantizer\":[42,79,133],\"every\":[44],\"particular\":[45],\"subband.\":[46,138],\"It\":[47],\"achieves\":[48,146],\"high\":[49],\"quality\":[50],\"output\":[51],\"at\":[52,82],\"bit\":[53],\"rates\":[54],\"from\":[55],\"0.1\":[56],\"0.9\":[58],\"bits/pixel\":[59],\"(bpp)\":[60],\"depending\":[61,164],\"complexity\":[64],\"of\":[65,89,104,159,168],\"image.\":[67,170],\"In\":[68,124],\"this\":[69],\"paper,\":[70],\"we\":[71],\"present\":[72],\"algorithm\":[74,172],\"that\":[75],\"locally\":[76],\"adapts\":[77],\"step\":[80,134],\"size\":[81,135],\"pixel\":[84],\"according\":[85],\"estimate\":[88,94],\"This\":[93],\"is\":[95,185,190],\"already\":[99],\"coded\":[100,108],\"pixels\":[101],\"predictions\":[103],\"not\":[106,118,191],\"yet\":[107],\"pixels.\":[109],\"Compared\":[110],\"PIC,\":[113],\"proposed\":[115,144],\"method\":[116,145],\"does\":[117],\"require\":[119],\"any\":[120],\"additional\":[121],\"side\":[122],\"information.\":[123],\"fact,\":[125],\"it\":[126],\"eliminates\":[127],\"need\":[129],\"transmit\":[131],\"For\":[139],\"comparable\":[140],\"quality,\":[142],\"compression\":[147,180],\"gains\":[148],\"up\":[149],\"40\":[151],\"percent.\":[152],\"Typical\":[153],\"values\":[154],\"order\":[158],\"20\":[160],\"30\":[162],\"percent,\":[163],\"nature\":[167],\"Our\":[171],\"has\":[173],\"also\":[174],\"better\":[175],\"performance\":[176],\"supra-threshold\":[178],\"since\":[181],\"error\":[184],\"distributed\":[186],\"more\":[187],\"evenly\":[188],\"concentrated\":[192],\"most\":[195],\"sensitive\":[196],\"regions.\":[197]}}"}
{"objectID":"44353701","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":232,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"Severe\":[0],\"coronary\":[1,13,83],\"artery\":[2,84],\"stenosis\":[3],\"with\":[4,43,205],\"endothelial\":[5],\"injury\":[6],\"in\":[7,55,124,187,202,230],\"the\":[8,28,32,79,101,104,112,139,180,200,203],\"canine\":[9],\"model\":[10],\"induces\":[11],\"cyclic\":[12],\"flow\":[14,88,96,129],\"variations\":[15],\"(CFVs),\":[16],\"which\":[17],\"are\":[18],\"partially\":[19],\"due\":[20],\"to\":[21,45,100,195,215],\"spontaneous\":[22],\"platelet\":[23],\"aggregation\":[24],\"and\":[25,39,59,68,103,116,135,172],\"dislodgement\":[26],\"at\":[27],\"stenotic\":[29],\"site.\":[30],\"In\":[31],\"present\":[33],\"study,\":[34],\"we\":[35],\"used\":[36],\"anesthetized\":[37],\"open-chest\":[38],\"unsedated\":[40],\"closed-chest\":[41],\"dogs\":[42,189,204],\"CFVs\":[44,58,61,70,107,115,191,206,211],\"investigate\":[46],\"whether\":[47,60],\"oxidative\":[48],\"metabolic\":[49],\"burst\":[50],\"(hydrogen\":[51],\"peroxide\":[52,122,227],\"generation)\":[53],\"occurred\":[54],\"neutrophils\":[56,125],\"during\":[57,210],\"were\":[62,71],\"attenuated\":[63],\"by\":[64,73,91,110,128],\"superoxide\":[65],\"dismutase\":[66],\"(SOD)\":[67],\"catalase.\":[69],\"produced\":[72],\"placing\":[74],\"a\":[75,94,168],\"cylindrical\":[76],\"constrictor\":[77],\"on\":[78],\"left\":[80],\"anterior\":[81],\"descending\":[82],\"(LAD).\":[85],\"LAD\":[86,118],\"blood\":[87,119],\"was\":[89,108,126,136,207],\"monitored\":[90],\"means\":[92],\"of\":[93,106,114,143,151,170],\"Doppler\":[95],\"probe\":[97],\"placed\":[98],\"proximally\":[99],\"constrictor,\":[102],\"severity\":[105],\"expressed\":[109,137],\"both\":[111],\"frequency\":[113],\"mean\":[117,140,181],\"flow.\":[120],\"Hydrogen\":[121],\"generation\":[123],\"measured\":[127],\"cytometry,\":[130],\"using\":[131],\"single\":[132],\"cell\":[133],\"analysis,\":[134],\"as\":[138],\"fluorescence\":[141,182],\"intensity\":[142,183,201],\"2\u2019,\":[144],\"7\u2019-dichlorofluorescein.\":[145],\"Dogs\":[146],\"received\":[147],\"an\":[148],\"intravenous\":[149],\"infusion\":[150],\"saline\":[152],\"(n\":[153],\"=\":[154,160,165,177],\"8),\":[155],\"SOD\":[156,171],\"(5\":[157],\"mg/kg,\":[158],\"n\":[159,164,176],\"7),\":[161,166],\"catalase\":[162,173],\"(5mg/kg,\":[163],\"or\":[167],\"combination\":[169],\"(same\":[174],\"doses,\":[175],\"7).\":[178],\"Although\":[179],\"did\":[184],\"not\":[185],\"change\":[186],\"sham-operated\":[188],\"without\":[190],\"(61.7\":[192],\"\u00b1\":[193,197,213,217],\"15.8\":[194],\"60.4\":[196],\"11.8;\":[198],\"NS),\":[199],\"significantly\":[208],\"increased\":[209],\"(62.2\":[212],\"13.7\":[214],\"79.8\":[216],\"9.8;\":[218],\"P\":[219],\"\\u003c\":[220],\"0.005).\":[221],\"These\":[222],\"results\":[223],\"indicate\":[224],\"that\":[225],\"hydrogen\":[226],\"is\":[228],\"generated\":[229],\"neutrophils.\":[231]}}"}
{"objectID":"2317258756","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":227,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"Administration\":[0],\"of\":[1,16,32,57,155,212],\"single\":[2,30,70],\"dose\":[3,31,71],\"nevirapine\":[4],\"(sdNVP)\":[5],\"to\":[6,11,18,68,106,123,187],\"mothers\":[7,127],\"at\":[8,88],\"delivery\":[9],\"and\":[10,78,95,177,194,214,217],\"their\":[12],\"newborns\":[13],\"for\":[14,45],\"prevention\":[15],\"mother\":[17],\"child\":[19],\"HIV\":[20],\"transmission\":[21,25],\"(PMTCT)\":[22],\"significantly\":[23,203],\"decreases\":[24],\"risk.1,2\":[26],\"However\":[27],\"even\":[28],\"a\":[29],\"NVP\":[33,72,162],\"can\":[34,43],\"induce\":[35],\"non-nucleoside\":[36],\"reverse\":[37],\"transcriptase\":[38],\"inhibitor\":[39],\"(NNRTI)\":[40],\"resistance\":[41],\"which\":[42],\"persist\":[44],\"more\":[46,170],\"than\":[47,182],\"six\":[48],\"months.3\":[49],\"Recent\":[50],\"trials\":[51,81],\"therefore\":[52],\"evaluated\":[53],\"whether\":[54,189,219],\"the\":[55,131,172,190],\"effectiveness\":[56],\"NVP-based\":[58,119,147],\"versus\":[59],\"protease\":[60],\"inhibitor-based\":[61],\"antiretroviral\":[62],\"therapy\":[63],\"(ART)\":[64],\"might\":[65],\"differ\":[66],\"according\":[67],\"prior\":[69,99],\"exposure\":[73,100,163],\"in\":[74,126,137,151,159,198],\"both\":[75,103],\"mothers4,\":[76],\"5\":[77],\"children.6,7\":[79],\"Both\":[80],\"included\":[82],\"cohorts\":[83],\"who\":[84,96],\"had\":[85,97,134],\"received\":[86],\"sdNVP\":[87],\"least\":[89],\"6\":[90],\"months\":[91],\"before\":[92],\"enrollment\":[93],\"(PrNVP)\":[94],\"no\":[98,207],\"(no\":[101],\"PrNVP);\":[102],\"randomized\":[104],\"participants\":[105],\"either\":[107],\"NVP-\":[108,193],\"or\":[109],\"lopinavir/ritonavir\":[110],\"(LPV/r)\":[111],\"\u2013\":[112],\"based\":[113],\"ART.\":[114],\"ACTG\":[115],\"5208\":[116],\"demonstrated\":[117],\"that\":[118,146],\"ART\":[120,125,148,196],\"was\":[121,149],\"inferior\":[122,150],\"LPV/r-based\":[124,195],\"with\":[128,200,206],\"PrNVP4,\":[129],\"but\":[130],\"two\":[132],\"regimens\":[133],\"similar\":[135],\"efficacy\":[136],\"previously\":[138],\"unexposed\":[139],\"mothers5.\":[140],\"In\":[141],\"contrast,\":[142],\"IMPAACT\":[143],\"P1060\":[144],\"found\":[145],\"young\":[152],\"children\":[153,160,199],\"regardless\":[154],\"PrNVP6,7.\":[156],\"This\":[157],\"finding\":[158],\"without\":[161],\"has\":[164],\"major\":[165],\"implications\":[166],\"since\":[167],\"LPV/r\":[168],\"is\":[169,179],\"expensive,\":[171],\"liquid\":[173],\"formulation\":[174],\"requires\":[175],\"refrigeration,\":[176],\"it\":[178],\"less\":[180],\"palatable\":[181],\"NVP.8\":[183],\"Our\":[184],\"objectives\":[185],\"were\":[186],\"investigate\":[188],\"differences\":[191,221],\"between\":[192],\"observed\":[197],\"PrNVP\":[201],\"differed\":[202],\"from\":[204],\"those\":[205],\"PrNVP,\":[208],\"identify\":[209],\"other\":[210,225],\"predictors\":[211],\"virologic\":[213],\"clinical\":[215],\"response,\":[216],\"determine\":[218],\"treatment\":[220],\"depended\":[222],\"on\":[223],\"these\":[224],\"predictors.\":[226]}}"}
{"objectID":"2831392535","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":202,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"PURPOSE:\":[0],\"To\":[1],\"simply\":[2],\"assemble\":[3],\"a\":[4,19,34,38,44,58,62,91,96,123,147,171,175,184,190,194],\"self-inking\":[5],\"stamp\":[6],\"by\":[7],\"coupling\":[8],\"both\":[9],\"control\":[10,51],\"straps\":[11,52,77,115,138],\"to\":[12,56,90,161],\"become\":[13,57],\"an\":[14,25,30,107,162],\"integral\":[15],\"U-shaped\":[16,59,86],\"member\":[17,60],\"via\":[18,61,183],\"connecting\":[20,63],\"piece\":[21,64,102,142],\"extended\":[22,105],\"upward\":[23],\"above\":[24,106],\"ink\":[26,108],\"pad,\":[27],\"and\":[28,140],\"providing\":[29],\"oscillating\":[31,81],\"protrusion\":[32,39],\"at\":[33,72,75],\"resilient\":[35,69],\"tongue\":[36],\"in\":[37,46,174],\"axis\":[40],\"direction\":[41],\"formed\":[42,71],\"of\":[43,95,113,122,131,136,179,197],\"slit\":[45],\"the\":[47,76,101,111,114,120,129,133,137,141,156,165,180,198],\"strap.\":[48],\"CONSTITUTION:\":[49],\"Both\":[50],\"12\":[53,116,139],\"are\":[54,70,159,168],\"coupled\":[55],\"14.\":[65],\"Tongues\":[66],\"16\":[67,158],\"being\":[68],\"slits\":[73],\"15\":[74],\"12,\":[78,88],\"which\":[79],\"hold\":[80],\"protrusions\":[82,166],\"17\":[83,167],\"for\":[84,193],\"supporting\":[85,172],\"members\":[87,134],\"14\":[89,103,143],\"short\":[92,176,199],\"side\":[93,177,200],\"wall\":[94,178],\"lower\":[97,148,195],\"portion\":[98,149,181],\"1.\":[99],\"Since\":[100],\"is\":[104,144],\"pad\":[109],\"11,\":[110],\"movements\":[112],\"do\":[117],\"not\":[118],\"disturb\":[119],\"movement\":[121],\"printing\":[124],\"plate\":[125],\"holder\":[126],\"8.\":[127],\"In\":[128,153],\"case\":[130],\"assembling,\":[132],\"made\":[135],\"introduced\":[145],\"into\":[146],\"1\":[150,182],\"from\":[151],\"below.\":[152],\"this\":[154],\"case,\":[155],\"tongues\":[157],\"urged\":[160],\"inside\":[163],\"until\":[164],\"engaged\":[169],\"with\":[170],\"opening\":[173],\"chamfered\":[185],\"part\":[186],\"18\":[187],\"serving\":[188],\"as\":[189],\"contact\":[191],\"surface\":[192],\"edge\":[196],\"wall.\":[201]}}"}
{"objectID":"1552493613","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":187,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"Prion\":[0,177],\"diseases\":[1,44,107],\"are\":[2,12,53,57,108],\"neurodegenerative\":[3],\"disorders\":[4],\"associated\":[5],\"with\":[6],\"misfolding\":[7],\"of\":[8,31,36,40,85,101,134,153,160,170],\"prion\":[9,32,43,86,106,116,135,163],\"protein.\":[10],\"They\":[11],\"transmissible,\":[13],\"often\":[14],\"rapidly\":[15],\"progressive,\":[16],\"fatal\":[17],\"conditions\":[18],\"that\":[19,56,131],\"occur\":[20,93],\"in\":[21,77,94,114,180],\"both\":[22,95],\"humans\":[23],\"and\":[24,28,48,62,68,98,120,158],\"animals.\":[25],\"Sporadic,\":[26],\"acquired,\":[27],\"inherited\":[29,99],\"forms\":[30,61,100],\"disease\":[33,80,103,126,136],\"exist.\":[34],\"One\":[35],\"the\":[37,96,102,115,154,161,174],\"distinct\":[38],\"characteristics\":[39],\"all\":[41,60],\"human\":[42,162],\"is\":[45,129,137,143],\"their\":[46],\"clinical\":[47,54,155],\"pathological\":[49],\"heterogeneity;\":[50],\"however,\":[51],\"there\":[52],\"features\":[55],\"common\":[58],\"to\":[59,92,148],\"these\":[63],\"include\":[64],\"progressive\":[65],\"cognitive\":[66],\"impairment\":[67],\"movement\":[69],\"disorders,\":[70],\"including\":[71],\"chorea.\":[72],\"Chorea\":[73],\"occurs\":[74],\"most\":[75],\"frequently\":[76],\"variant\":[78],\"Creutzfeldt-Jakob\":[79],\"(vCJD),\":[81],\"an\":[82],\"acquired\":[83],\"form\":[84],\"disease,\":[87],\"but\":[88],\"has\":[89],\"been\":[90],\"reported\":[91],\"sporadic\":[97],\"too.\":[104],\"Inherited\":[105],\"caused\":[109],\"by\":[110,166],\"autosomal\":[111],\"dominant\":[112],\"mutations\":[113],\"protein\":[117],\"gene\":[118,141],\"(PRNP)\":[119],\"can\":[121],\"be\":[122],\"mistaken\":[123],\"for\":[124],\"Huntington\u2019s\":[125],\"(HD).\":[127],\"It\":[128],\"important\":[130],\"a\":[132,150,184],\"diagnosis\":[133],\"considered\":[138],\"if\":[139],\"HD\":[140],\"testing\":[142],\"negative.\":[144],\"This\":[145],\"chapter\":[146],\"aims\":[147],\"give\":[149],\"general\":[151],\"overview\":[152],\"features,\":[156],\"investigations,\":[157],\"pathophysiology\":[159],\"diseases,\":[164],\"accompanied\":[165],\"representative\":[167],\"case\":[168],\"reports\":[169],\"patients\":[171],\"seen\":[172],\"at\":[173],\"NHS\":[175],\"National\":[176],\"Clinic,\":[178],\"UK,\":[179],\"whom\":[181],\"chorea\":[182],\"was\":[183],\"prominent\":[185],\"feature.\":[186]}}"}
{"objectID":"1497663348","indexed_abstract":"{\"IndexLength\":1,\"InvertedIndex\":{\"\u201c\u4ea4\u8fd8\u201d\u4e00\u8bcd,\u5728\u5927\u591a\u6570\u8f9e\u4e66\u4e2d\u89e3\u91ca\u4e3a\u5f52\u8fd8,\u8fd9\u662f\u65e0\u53ef\u7f6e\u7591\u7684;\u7136\u800c\u9664\u6b64\u4e4b\u5916,\u5728\u4e70\u5356\u3001\u79df\u8d41\u3001\u5178\u5f53\u7b49\u5185\u5bb9\u7684\u5951\u7ea6\u6587\u4e66\u4e2d,\u5b83\u8fd8\u53ef\u4ee5\u8868\u793a\u4ea4\u7ed9\u3001\u4ed8\u7ed9,\u5176\u4e2d\u7684\u201c\u8fd8\u201d\u6ca1\u6709\u8868\u4e49,\u8bcd\u4e49\u7531\u201c\u4ea4\u201d\u5b57\u627f\u62c5,\u5373\u201c\u4ea4\u8fd8\u201d\u53d1\u5c55\u4e3a\u4e00\u4e2a\u504f\u4e49\u590d\u8bcd.\":[0]}}"}
```

Comment: how data look like in input table for those objectid's which returned "empty", show just few of them so we can help you. i just did quick test and was not able to reproduce this behavior. so some data example - ideally matching above output  - will help

Comment: I have just added data example for those I have got empty response.

Comment: consult https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

Comment: I just loaded you json file and run the query against it and output is as expected  - ALL objectIDs processed as expected and no "empty" rows . Meantime  - just to note - I loaded 96 records from your file - not 100 as if I would expect based on file name

Comment: Yes there were 96 rows actually. But I really don't understand why I am getting the empty rows. Pretty weird. Does it really have to do anything with the quotas?

Comment: This is mysterious, I re-uploaded my input file and tried the query, I still get most of the output rows keyword field empty, just as before!

Comment: I have reproduced your scenario and got your same result. I was running some tests and I believe there must be some kind of issue in the json. Removing entries 12 and 13 allow further results, and then stops again in what would be entry 17 of the original file. Then, removing 17 and 18 allows to go up to entry 25 of the original file. I have tried using the API directly and the result is again the same: after row 12, the rest is empty. Now, this must be either something wrong with the json or with the API.
@MikhailBerlyant, did you pre-processed the json file somehow?

Comment: nope - just downloaded it used it as is

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez Could I find any reason why it is happening?