# In BigQuery, convert stringified array of objects into non-stringified

Tags: google-bigquery

I am ingesting `.json` data into Google BigQuery, and on the ingest, the data types for `arrays` and `objects` from the `.json` are both being cast into `string` columns. The data in BigQuery then looks like this:

```
select 1 as id, '[]' as stringCol1, '[]' as stringCol2 union all
select 2 as id, null as stringCol1, null as stringCol2 union all
select 3 as id, "{'game': '22', 'year': 'sophomore'}" as stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamA', 'teamAge': 37}, {'teamName': 'teamB', 'teamAge': 32]" as stringCol2 union all
select 4 as id, "{'game': '17', 'year': 'freshman'}" as stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamA', 'teamAge': 32}, {'teamName': 'teamB', 'teamAge': 33]" as stringCol2 union all
select 5 as id, "{'game': '9', 'year': 'senior'}" as stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamC', 'teamAge': 31}, {'teamName': 'teamD', 'teamAge': 17]" as stringCol2 union all
select 6 as id, "{'game': '234', 'year': 'junior'}" as stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamC', 'teamAge': 42}, {'teamName': 'teamD', 'teamAge': 25]" as stringCol2
```

[image]

The data is a bit messy.

- In `stringCol1`, there are both `null` and `'[]'` values for missing data. I'd like to create the 2 columns `game` and `year` from this stringified object.
- For `stringCol2`, this is always an array with 2 objects, with identical keys (`teamName` and `teamAge`, in this case). This then needs to be cast into the 4 columns `teamName1`, `teamAge1`, `teamName2`, `teamAge2`.

[This similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46199823/how-to-convert-stringified-array-into-array-in-bigquery) addressed converting a basic stringified array into a not-stringified array, but this example here is a bit more complex. In particular, the solution in that other post does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(stringCol1, '$.game') AS game,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(stringCol1, '$.year') AS year,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t1, '$.teamName') AS teamName1,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t1, '$.teamAge') AS teamAge1,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t2, '$.teamName') AS teamName2,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t2, '$.teamAge') AS teamAge2
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(stringCol2)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] AS t1, 
  JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(stringCol2)[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS t2
)])
```

If to apply to sample data from your question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '[]' AS stringCol1, '[]' AS stringCol2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS id, NULL AS stringCol1, NULL AS stringCol2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS id, "{'game': '22', 'year': 'sophomore'}" AS stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamA', 'teamAge': 37}, {'teamName': 'teamB', 'teamAge': 32}]" AS stringCol2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS id, "{'game': '17', 'year': 'freshman'}" AS stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamA', 'teamAge': 32}, {'teamName': 'teamB', 'teamAge': 33}]" AS stringCol2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5 AS id, "{'game': '9', 'year': 'senior'}" AS stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamC', 'teamAge': 31}, {'teamName': 'teamD', 'teamAge': 17}]" AS stringCol2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 AS id, "{'game': '234', 'year': 'junior'}" AS stringCol1, "[{'teamName': 'teamC', 'teamAge': 42}, {'teamName': 'teamD', 'teamAge': 25}]" AS stringCol2
)
```

output is

```
Row id  game    year        teamName1   teamAge1    teamName2   teamAge2     
1   1   null    null        null        null        null        null     
2   2   null    null        null        null        null        null     
3   3   22      sophomore   teamA       37          teamB       32   
4   4   17      freshman    teamA       32          teamB       33   
5   5   9       senior      teamC       31          teamD       17   
6   6   234     junior      teamC       42          teamD       25
```

There can be quite a number of variations of above to improve readability for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(stringCol1, '$.game') AS game,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(stringCol1, '$.year') AS year,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '$.teamName') AS teamName1,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t[SAFE_OFFSET(0)], '$.teamAge') AS teamAge1,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], '$.teamName') AS teamName2,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(t[SAFE_OFFSET(1)], '$.teamAge') AS teamAge2
FROM `project.dataset.table`,
UNNEST([STRUCT(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(stringCol2) AS t)])
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. `json_extract_*` seems like a powerful function in BigQuery